# PyCharm: Is it possible to auto complete those keyword-arguments(**kwargs)?

Tags: pycharm

So I don't have to memorize those keyword arguments, for example:

```
np.nditer(op_f) --(tab or so)--> np.nditer(op_flags=)  
                --(tab or so)--> np.nditer(op_flags=['read'])
```

I like PyCharm and I hope this is possible, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, pycharm needs proper signature to predict keyword arguments, otherwise it's impossible to know what's the signature.

To illustrate the issue take a look at this example.

```
def person_talk(**kwargs):
    text = 'foobar '
    if kwargs.get('name'):
        text += name
```

To autocomplete `name` kwarg pycharm would have to read the whole function to understand what are the possibilities for kwargs.

For this reason kwargs patterns are being looked down and on not recommended, however sometimes they are unavoidable.